# Upper and lower bound for seminorm induced by matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I have the following situation. Given a positive definite diagonal matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix $A$ I want to prove that
\begin{align}
c\langle Ax,x\rangle \le \langle DAx,x\rangle \le C\langle Ax,x\rangle,
\end{align}
where $c,C>0$ are such that for all $i=1,...,n$ we have $c\le D_{ii}\le C$.
EDIT: THE FOLLOWING SENTENCE IS WRONF
I already know that $DA$ is positive semi-definite, so the existence of suitable constants for the upper and lower bound is clear.
END-EDIT
But I need them to be controlled by the $D_{ii}$. Therefore, my "suggestion" for the constants is possible, but I am also happy if you replace $c,C$ by $c(D_{11},...,D_{nn}), C(D_{11},...,D_{nn})$. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: *“I already know that $DA$ is positive semi-definite.”* In general, $DA$ does not always have a PSD symmetric part. Do you mean that your $DA$ *happens to be* positive semidefinite?

Comment: I thought I could prove that DA in general has a PSD symmetric part. But this was based on a mistake. So this sentence is not true, I do not know that.

Comment: Consider $D=\pmatrix{1\\ &t}$ and $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&c}$ with $b\ne0$. When $t\to0$, $DA\to\pmatrix{a&b\\ 0&0}$ and the symmetric part of $DA$ tends to $\pmatrix{a&b/2\\ b/2&0}$, which is indefinite. Hence the symmetric part of $DA$ is indefinite when $t$ is sufficiently small.